# Is this possible to see seams from Collada imported object?

Tags: modeling, uv, collada

Newbie to blender here, I'm trying to replicate an object I downloaded, I now need to unwrap it but I'm not familiar with this method and I'm lost.
I was wondering if it's possible to see seams from an imported Collada (.dae) file, I try to figure it out by myself but I didn't manage to find out.

Here's the file if you need :

[image]

Comment: Please use https://blend-exchange.com/ to share .blend files, following the instructions there. Better for the archive, and we don't have to wait for bogus delay-mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks for telling I didn't knew, I edited my post and added the link.

Comment: Thanks for that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Than you import collada file:

1. Select all points and press <kbd>M</kbd> -> By distance. It will merdge together all hard edges.
2. then open up uv editor, select all points and click UV -> Seams from islands.

[image]

This will redo all seams from UV map

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works